# Why do textbooks teach が as "but" when けど is more common?

Tags: conjunctions

I personally learned beginner Japanese using the Genki textbooks, though I think this is similar for other beginner textbooks. In these textbooks, they teach が to mean "but", as in "日本料理が好きです**が**、生卵が嫌いです。" However, when I was in Japan this past summer, I don't believe I ever heard people use が this way. けど was so much more common, and when people wanted to be formal, they used けれど or けれども. (I was in Nagoya, so it may be a regional thing.)

Why do textbooks teach が when けど seems so much more commonly used?

Comment: The ga is commonly used in newspapers, novels, essays, news announcements. Do your textbooks teach only spoken/colloquial Japanese?

Comment: I think the answer to this question will be somewhat opinion-based, but my belief is that language teaching (whether L1 or L2) always contains a political component of how certain parties want you to speak / write. In this case of Japanese, they try to make foreigners speak politely -- thus they don't want you saying けど for "but" instead of が

Comment: I stubled on this book in my first few months in Japan and learning Japanese from scratch and it really did it for me. It will show you I think around 20 uses af GA among many other Particles.  https://www.amazon.com/All-About-Particles-Handbook-Japanese/dp/1568364199

Comment: @virmaior I think it's less a nefarious cabal of JFL teachers trying to make non-native speakers into mealy-mouthed patsies and more the idea that the potential for disaster is smaller when you err on the polite side rather than the casual side. Especially in Japan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just my personal opinion but as I am living in Tokyo now, I've only heard people saying が very few times too. In my textbooks, I was taught that けど is the informal form of が　so in the beginning I didn't dare to use it until I heard most people do. けど　is much more frequently used in daily conversations, regardless of the circumstances.
In terms of けれども, I hear it very often during speeches or formal meetings, so I believe it is neither uncommon nor regional, but of course awkward if you use it in casual conversations.

Answer (score -2):

In each of spoken & written categories, i think 
「が」 is at least 3 times as common as  「けれども」 and variants ( 「だけど」 「けれど」 「けど」 「けども」 ... ) combined.

---

I think textbooks all over the world respect the (formal) [written word]  over the (casual) [spoken word].

What's a good example in English  ?

- No introductory textbook of English begin with "gonna", "ain't", ... etc.
- U.S. elementary schools teach the pronuciation "Twen-tee"  when "Twa-nee" is much more common.

Other (better) examples    ?

```
    and, Yes, we love it when foreigners speak polite and over-polite Japanese.
```

> http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/68969/meaning/m0u/
>
> [補説] 「けれども」は中世末、形容詞活用の已然形語尾に接続助詞「ども」が付いてできたもの。近世前期になると、くだけた感じを伴う「けれど」「けど」が生じ、後期には、「けども」が成立した。

「けれども」 is longer and more awkward.

It can sound too colloquial for an  introductory textbook. -- 「が」 is just as good, or better.

「が」 sounds more modern. -- 「けれども」 can sound old-fashioned. like Kobun.

Comment: However, why teach が instead of けれども, which is also quite formal? Is it because けれども is more of a spoken word?

Comment: Ga plays such a huge  role in grammar and creating the direction and feel of a sentence. Ga carries more meanings than "but"  as shared with けれども and the ability to distinguish that is key understanding a sentence. The book I mentioned on the original post offers over 10 ways GA becomes different in meaning in English. Learn the base, then the manipulation. for example, you learn けど/けれど first then a unit comes up saying "oh you can also use が in this case....but が also means this, this, this, this and this...oh and this. Or learn が then learn けれど can replace this one usage of が..